# Prove that $\int_x^{x + {\ln x\over x}} e^{t^2} \,dt> {e^{x^2}\ln x\over2x}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_x^{x + {\ln x\over x}} e^{t^2} \,dt> {e^{x^2}\ln x\over2x}\\x > 1,$$ 
I wanted to start with integrating $e^{t^2}$, but unfortunately it's not helpful. What's the way to solve inequality like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any integral which has a positive increasing integrand is greater than or equal to its minimum value multiplied by the width of the integration region. So, in this case
$$\int_x^{x + {lnx\over x}} e^{t^2} \,dt\ge\frac{e^{x^2}\ln{(x)}}{x}\gt\frac{e^{x^2}\ln{(x)}}{2x}$$

Comment: And by looking at the 2nd derivative, you can get better estimates. I feel that OP was missing something because this answer was so immediate.